# What is the meaning/significance/importance of 'order of interpolation' used in Mathematica?

Tags: interpolation

You can find details here - https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html.

Comment: It's the (maximal) order/degree of the polynomial pieces used in the interpolation.

Comment: Thanks. But could you kindly say a little bit more? What are the polynomial pieces?

Comment: [Piecewise polynomial interpolation](https://www.google.com/search?q=piecewise+polynomial+interpolation) is a standard topic in mathematics/scientific computation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a set of *n* points there are two main ways of performing interpolation. You either fit a degree *n* polynomial to the whole dataset (has some issues due to the fact that the polynomial degree is very high), or you may fit a degree *k* polynomial in a piecewise manner to the neighborhood of each data point. Interpolation functions in Mathematica follow the second option. Interpolation order will be the value of *k*. I suggest you look into [spline interpolation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) for more information.